# Trace/BPT trap... something to do with fastthread?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a rails 2.3.8 web app in mac os x 10.6 development environment. On this macbook pro the system version of Ruby is 1.8.7. Using RVM i installed 1.9.2.

I am getting "Trace/BPT trap" which shuts down the server. I read that this has to do with not having the correct version of fastthread which solves a memory leak problem in mongrel. Is this true?

I uninstalled fastthread 1.0.7 and tried to install v 1.0.1 but it wouldn't install. Also tried installing 1.0.2 and same result. Was able to install 1.0.3. However, this version didn't fix the problem. Still getting the Trace/BPT trap error.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Surprised i didn't get any responses on this.

Via RVM i installed 1.8.7 that i am using in lieu of 1.9.2 or the system version 1.8.7

In that the Rails version is 2.3.8 i installed an earlier version of rubygems (1.3.6)

I don't know why... but this solved the Trace/BPT trap.